# Docker: How to know what version of Ubuntu 22.04 is referred to an Index Digest?

Tags: 22.04, docker

I'm currently using the Ubuntu 22.04 Docker Image for work.
I thought if I used a tag that would keep the Image constant until I noticed a month ago that the Ubuntu 22.04 image got updated.

I noticed that each update came with a SHA hash digest that I could also use to pull the image. My problem is how can I know which version of Ubuntu 22.04 gets pulled based on the digest I used?

Right now, the latest version is Ubuntu 22.04.4. I'd like to make sure that that's the one I'm getting. I haven't found documentation that associates the digest with the Ubuntu version.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the ask Ubuntu forum.

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question, but this may be a simple solution.

From Terminal:

`lsb_release -a`

This will give a description, release number, and the codename.  Mine shows Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and jammy.

Comment: Note that `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` will automatically fetch what has changed in the most recent images, assuming you have internet connection in your Docker image.

Comment: Thank you for both your answers! I'll try them out and see if it fits our use cases.